# Shiny: Provide context menu on right click in numericInput?

Tags: r, shiny

I have been asked to create something I'm not sure is possible in Shiny: a context menu that appears when a user right-clicks on a numeric input. I know how to show a context popup on a chart (see code below), but this doesn't help me answer the following:

- Can an input widget catch a click / hover / right click event?
- Can I generate a Shiny menu in this kind of popup window?

I'm happy to receive answers along the lines of 'not possible' or 'not possible unless you learn all of Javascript today'. If so I will think of another way to incorporate this kind of context-sensitive response in the interface.

Example code that produces a hovering window on click on a chart:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         numericInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30
                     )
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot", click = "plotclick"),
         uiOutput("plotClickInfo")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

   })

   output$plotClickInfo <- renderUI({
     click <- input$plotclick
     ## Find the KPI
     if (!is.null(click)){
       aText <- "More text"
       aLabel <- 'my label'
       # calculate point position INSIDE the image as percent of total dimensions
       # from left (horizontal) and from top (vertical)
       left_pct <- (click$x - click$domain$left) / (click$domain$right - click$domain$left)
       top_pct <- (click$domain$top - click$y) / (click$domain$top - click$domain$bottom)

       # calculate distance from left and bottom side of the picture in pixels
       left_px <- click$range$left + left_pct * (click$range$right - click$range$left)
       top_px <- click$range$top + top_pct * (click$range$bottom - click$range$top)

       # create style property fot tooltip
       # background color is set so tooltip is a bit transparent
       # z-index is set so we are sure are tooltip will be on top
       style <- paste0("position:absolute; z-index:100; background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.85); max-width: 200px;",
                       "left:", left_px + 2, "px; top:", top_px + 2, "px;")

       # actual tooltip created as wellPanel
       wellPanel(
         style = style,
         p(HTML(paste0("<b> KPI: </b>", aLabel, "<br/>",
                       "<b> Information: </b>", aText)))
       )
     }
     else return(NULL)
   })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use wonderful `shinyjs` package which has a lot of event listeners built. Have a look at his docs https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyjs/shinyjs.pdf. If you want to reconcile some `jquery` events look here http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Here is an example of some of them you might find useful, I think the right click is the `mousedown` event, but you can check

```
#onclick("bins", v$click <- rnorm(1))
#onevent("hover", "bins", v$click <- rnorm(1))
#onevent("dblclick", "bins", v$click <- rnorm(1))
onevent("mousedown", "bins", v$click <- rnorm(1))
```

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("bins","Number of bins:",min = 1,max = 50,value = 30),
      uiOutput("plotClickInfo")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot", click = "plotclick")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

  })

  v <- reactiveValues()


  #onclick("bins", v$click <- rnorm(1))
  #onevent("hover", "bins", v$click <- rnorm(1))
  #onevent("dblclick", "bins", v$click <- rnorm(1))
  onevent("mousedown", "bins", v$click <- rnorm(1))

  output$plotClickInfo <- renderUI({
    if (!is.null(v$click)){
      aText <- "More text"
      aLabel <- paste0('my label - ',v$click)
      wellPanel(
        p(HTML(paste0("<b> KPI: </b>", aLabel, "<br/>","<b> Information: </b>", aText)))
      )
    }
    else return(NULL)
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This has been very helpful, and has allowed me to create a popup menu that sits next to an 'info' image, combining some of the other code snippets that I have collected over the previous two weeks. I am posting my final code below.

Answer (score 3):

Following the excellent pointers by @Pork Chop and some previous code that I had, I have finished with the following code (note in the end I have gone with clicking on an icon / image next to the widget label rather than inside the widget; this purely to avoid confusing the user, and because the right click (for which the event is `contextmenu`) brings up a browser-specific context menu already. The code remembers the numbers that the user has entered and gives feedback where the totals go over or under 100% (relevant in my case). It also only accepts the entries if they add up to exactly 100%, otherwise the context menu will not disappear.

I know this answer goes beyond my initial question but I hope it may be helpful for someone trying to do the same or similar.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

initialValues <- c(25, 25, 25, 25)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      p(id = "coords", "Click me to see the mouse coordinates"), ## Example of the mouse click feedback

      div(style='display: inline-block;',
          "Click here for info",
          img(id = "image", src='https://www.zorro.com/wp-content/uploads/cc_resize/005-1200x542.jpg',height='30px',style='display: inline-block;', click = "image_click")
      ),
      uiOutput("plotClickInfo"),
      numericInput("bins",NULL,min = 1,max = 50,value = 30)

    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot", click = "plotclick")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

  })

  v <- reactiveValues()

  onclick("coords", function(event) { alert(event) })

  ## Examples of other events we might use
  #onclick("bins", v$click <- rnorm(1))
  #onevent("hover", "bins", v$click <- rnorm(1))
  #onevent("dblclick", "bins", v$click <- rnorm(1))
  #onevent("mousedown", "bins", v$click <- rnorm(1))

  ## The actual event we have used.
  onclick("image", function(event) {v$clickX <- event$pageX
                                    v$clickY <- event$pageY
                                    ## Store the initial values of the controls.
                                    if (!is.null(input$perc1)) {
                                      initialValues[1] <- input$perc1
                                    }
                                    else {
                                      v$perc1Value <- initialValues[1]
                                    }

                                    if (!is.null(input$perc2)) {
                                      initialValues[2] <- input$perc2
                                    }
                                    else {
                                      v$perc2Value <- initialValues[2]
                                    }

                                    if (!is.null(input$perc3)) {
                                      initialValues[3] <- input$perc3
                                    }
                                    else {
                                      v$perc3Value <- initialValues[3]
                                    }

                                    if (!is.null(input$perc4)) {
                                      initialValues[4] <- input$perc4
                                    }
                                    else {
                                      v$perc4Value <- initialValues[4]
                                    } 
                                    })

  output$plotClickInfo <- renderUI({

    if (!is.null(v$clickX)){
      style <- paste0("position:absolute; z-index:100; background-color: rgba(100, 245, 245, 0.85); max-width: 250px; width: 250px;",
                                          "left:", v$clickX + 2, "px; top:", v$clickY - 50, "px;")

                          # actual tooltip created as wellPanel
                          wellPanel(
                            style = style,
                            p(HTML(paste0("<b> KPI: </b>", "bla", "<br/>",
                                          "<b> Information: </b>", "aText"))),
                            numericInput("perc1", "Percentage1", v$perc1Value, 0, 100, width="100%"),
                            numericInput("perc2", "Percentage2", v$perc2Value, 0, 100, width="100%"),
                            numericInput("perc3", "Percentage3", v$perc3Value, 0, 100, width="100%"),
                            numericInput("perc4", "Percentage4", v$perc4Value, 0, 100, width="100%"),
                            conditionalPanel(style = "color: red;", condition = "(input.perc1 + input.perc2 + input.perc3 +
                                                                                   input.perc4 > 100)",
                                             "Total of percentages cannot exceed 100%"),
                            conditionalPanel(style = "color: red;", condition = "(input.perc1 + input.perc2 + input.perc3 +
                                                                                   input.perc4 < 100)",
                                             "Total of percentages must add up to 100%"),
                            actionButton("myAction", "Go"), actionButton("myCancel", "Cancel")
                          )
    }
    else return(NULL)
  })

  observeEvent(input$myAction, {
    ## Only disappear this popup
    if (input$perc1 + input$perc2 + input$perc3 + input$perc4 == 100) {
      v$perc1Value <- input$perc1
      v$perc2Value <- input$perc2
      v$perc3Value <- input$perc3
      v$perc4Value <- input$perc4
      v$clickX = NULL
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$myCancel, {
    ## Revert to original values.
    updateNumericInput(session, "perc1", initialValues[1])
    updateNumericInput(session, "perc2", initialValues[2])
    updateNumericInput(session, "perc3", initialValues[3])
    updateNumericInput(session, "perc4", initialValues[4])
    v$clickX = NULL
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```